# CollectionViewをドラッグアンドドロップするためにUILongPressGestureRecognizerを設定したがロングプレスしても反応がない

Tags: swift

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]カスタムセルをのコレクションビューをドラッグアンドドロップするコードを書きました。
Swiftのバージョンは2.2です。

やりたいこととしては、ナビゲーションバーの`editButton`を押してから、セルを長押してドラッグアンドドロップしてセルの配列を変更するというものです。

しかしながら、ビルドは通るものの、セルを長押ししても何も反応しませんし動きません。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer?
    var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
    var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0)

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        self.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(GoodCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GoodCell")
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(BadCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BadCell")
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(TeacherCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TeacherCell")
        self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePanGesture(_:)))
    //self.panGesture?.enabled = false
    self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture!)
    //panGesture?.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.panGesture!)

    longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongGesture(_:)))
    longPressGesture?.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    self.longPressGesture?.enabled = false
    self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.longPressGesture!)
    //longPressGesture!.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.longPressGesture!)
    }

    func autolayoutSubviews() {    self.collectionView!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellTypeNumber = indexPath.item % 3
        switch cellTypeNumber {
        case 0:
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GoodCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GoodCell
            cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            return cell1

        case 1:
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BadCell
            cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            return cell2

        default:
            let cell3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TeacherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeacherCell
            cell3.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            return cell3
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }

    func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            break
        default:
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        }
    }

    func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch (gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath!)
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
```

func LongGesture(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        print("LongPressed")

```
}

}

extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouledRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer
            == longPressGesture {
            return panGesture
                == otherGestureRecognizer
        }
        if gestureRecognizer
            == panGesture {
            return longPressGesture == otherGestureRecognizer
        }
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer ==
            self.panGesture else {
                return true
        }
        return selectedIndexPath != nil
    } 
}
```

Comment: 上記のコードである程度動くと思いますよ。まず問題の切り分けのために`handleLongGesture(_:)`と`handlePanGesture(_:)`が呼ばれてるかどうか確認してください。やり方がよくわからなければ、とりあえず、これらのメソッドの先頭に`print()`メソッドで何か出力するようにしてみてください。

Comment: 削除する場合は左下に削除のリンクがあるのでがあるのでそちらをご利用ください。また、(知っておられると思いますが)解決した場合には削除でなく、回答を承認するようにしてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ロングプレスのジェスチャが反応しない理由はよおそらく、`UIPanGestureRecognizer`が先に動作してしまっているためだと思います。クラッシュは`handlePanGesture(_:)`メソッドで起こっているので。クラッシュの直接の原因は`handleLongGesture(_:)`が呼ばれてないために`selectedIndexPath`が`nil`のままだからです。

現在のコードにはいろいろと無駄なコードがあるのでそれを削って試してみてください。クラッシュしている`UIPanGestureRecognizer`もセルの移動には必要ありません。

セルの移動は`UICollectionView`の`〜InteractiveMovement()`メソッドが担当してくれるので、`UIPanGestureRecognizer`は不要です。

あと、`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`は設定していないので、エクステンションも不要です。

さらに、ジェスチャを`collectionView`と`view`の両方に追加していますが、`collectionView`だけでいいです。

不要な部分を除いたコードが下記になります。こちらで試してみてください。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer?
    var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupSubviews()
        self.autolayoutSubviews()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
        flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 100.0)

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        self.collectionView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView!.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView!.delegate = self
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(GoodCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "GoodCell")
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(BadCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "BadCell")
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(TeacherCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "TeacherCell")
        self.collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

        longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleLongGesture(_:)))
        longPressGesture?.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
        self.longPressGesture?.enabled = false
        self.collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.longPressGesture!)
    }

    func autolayoutSubviews() {    self.collectionView!.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.topAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.trailingAnchor).active = true
        self.collectionView!.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.bottomAnchor).active = true
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cellTypeNumber = indexPath.item % 3
        switch cellTypeNumber {
        case 0:
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("GoodCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GoodCell
            cell1.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            return cell1

        case 1:
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("BadCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BadCell
            cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
            return cell2

        default:
            let cell3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("TeacherCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TeacherCell
            cell3.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            return cell3
        }
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    }

    func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch(gesture.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
            guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView?.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(collectionView!)) else {
                break
            }
            collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
            collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
        case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
            collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
        default:
            collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 見落としてましたが、`self.longPressGesture?.enabled = false`という行があなたの前回の編集で増えてますね。`enabled = false`だとそもそもlongPressGestureを無効にするということなので、この行を消してみてください。